# What is the proper way to include bootstrap in my application.css.scss file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, import, sass, bootstrap-modal

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this file, app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss (don’t ask me why, when I created the project, Rails just automatically created this file for me).

```
/*
…
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery-ui
 */

html {
    background-image: url(/assets/tile.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

I wanted to add bootstrap, and various tutorials recommended I added “@import” statements to make it work.  So I tried

```
…
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap/theme'

html {
    background-image: url(/assets/tile.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

but now when I load my page I get the error

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Users#edit

Invalid CSS after "html ": expected selector or at-rule, was "{"
```

What is the proper way to include the bootstrap directives in my application.css.scss file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to terminate your last import with a semicolon.

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap/theme';

html {
    background-image: url(/assets/tile.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally i prefer importing all my assets over scss.

Add the bootstrap gem to the Gemfile, https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap.
Create a folder `bootstrap_and_overrides` in `app/assets/stylesheets` and `app/assets/javascripts`.

```
app
 |_assets
   |_javascripts
     |_bootstrap_and_overrides
       |_bootstrap.js 
   |_stylesheets
     |_bootstrap_and_overrides
       |_bootstrap.scss
       |_variables.scss
       |_overrides.scss
```

Your `application.js` looks something like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap_and_overrides/bootstrap
```

And your `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap_and_overrides/variables";
@import "bootstrap_and_overrides/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap_and_overrides/overrides";
```

Example for `bootstrap.js` on your javascript assets. With this you can choose what to load and what not:

```
//= require bootstrap/util
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
// require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
// require bootstrap/modal
// require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
```

Example for `bootstrap.scss` in your stylesheet assets:

```
// Core variables and mixins
//@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/print";
// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/images";
//@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/buttons";
// Components
@import "bootstrap/animation";
@import "bootstrap/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/button-group";
//@import "bootstrap/input-group";
//@import "bootstrap/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/nav";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/card";
@import "bootstrap/breadcrumb";
@import "bootstrap/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/pager";
@import "bootstrap/labels";
//@import "bootstrap/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/alert";
@import "bootstrap/progress";
@import "bootstrap/media";
@import "bootstrap/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-embed";
@import "bootstrap/close";
// Components w/ JavaScript
//@import "bootstrap/modal";
@import "bootstrap/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/popover";
//@import "bootstrap/carousel";
// Utility classes
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/utilities-background";
@import "bootstrap/utilities-spacing";
@import "bootstrap/utilities-responsive";
```

This two files are simply a copied version from the bootstrap gem. The `variables.scss` is also the standard variables file from the bootstrap gem. 
I think this is the best possible way to include bootstrap to your rails project with total control of what to load and what not.